# Is there a tutorial in Terraria? If so, How do I start it?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile, terraria-console

I'm quite new to Terraria, and when I created and entered my first world, there was no guide or walkthrough on how to play the game. Am I missing something? Or is there a specific way to start the tutorial? Or is there just no tutorial?

Comment: What makes you think there would be one?

Comment: Well why would'nt there be one . I found the game complicated to play and just need help.

Comment: Something like [this](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Getting_started) is probably your best bet.  Not a tutorial, but it is helpful.

Comment: this is actually a pretty good question. After all, why wouldnt it? Every game does, in one way or another. Adding the other terraria tags, as this applies to all the current platforms.

Comment: Given Terraria is actually a fairly open world exploration/building game, the lack of tutorial is really overwhelming to a new player.  Not everyone has played minecraft and knows to start beating on your nearest tree.  It's one of those things that you just don't do unless you know about it.

Comment: I have played minecraft before an at least there is a tutorial world where you can learn the basics. With terraria you get...well nothing. Lets hope they will add some form of tutorial at a future data

Comment: @MichealNx Minecraft doesn't have a built in tutorial world, presumably that's something you downloaded. If you've played minecraft though, the only major differences are the lack of hunger, the 2D-ness and the crafting recipes (all of which can be found on the wiki).

Comment: @Pharap Although MC doesn't have a direct tutorial, the achievements do have a sort of tutorial-esque nature to them. They flow and lead to what you are assumed and encouraged to do in a logical fashion. Terraria has achievements that could be considered to have similar utility, but not the same UI flow. If you want to know what your next goal *could* be, look at the achievements.

Comment: @zero298 thank all of you for the help im finding the game easier now

Comment: I haven't played in a while - can you no longer create a tutorial world, that gives you the pit to climb out of etc?

Comment: @CodeMoose I dont think so when i started it gave no tutorial was there :(

Comment: I could suggest looking at a boss progression chain if you ever get stuck. Spoilers are everywhere, be vigilant.

Comment: @MichealNx it looks like the tutorial world is still an option http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tutorial

Comment: @Timelord64 As the question was originally explicitly tagged "PC" in addition to the PC Terraria tag, and it's come to light that the answer is actually different on non-PC platforms, I've reverted the tags back to only reference the PC version.

Comment: @MikeKellogg, but at the same time, youve added a part dedicated ro console in your answer? The tags are to help people identify answers as much as questions. If the console tag shouldnt be there, neither should the console answer.

Comment: Theres also no tutorial in my xbox 360 version so your console answer isnt 100% either..

Comment: @Timelord64 Yeah, I admit that was a little dumb, but I changed the tags and made the comment first before thinking I should update my answer. Though, to be fair, the console/mobile part is more a footnote of extra information on the main PC answer, I think it's valid for an answer to include extra information that is related to but not strictly part of the question. Changing the tags to include other systems _technically_ seems to be going against the asker's intent and should be left to his opinion, but I don't care enough to argue about it, so change it back if you disagree.

Comment: @Timelord64 Regarding the 360 version, you may need to update, because there _is_ a tutorial map in the 360 version. https://youtu.be/BSIKKPdqzlo Video's playing the tutorial map, gets a 360 achievement at about 1:52. If you're fully updated already, then I don't know what to tell you, but it's supposed to be there.

Answer (score 30):

### The PC version of Terraria does not have a distinct tutorial

As more-or-less a sandbox game, Terraria does not have a formalized tutorial. The keyboard controls can be viewed and customized in the menu, but other than that, it's expected for a player to learn most of the basics simply through experimenting while playing the game. Still, there are two main sources of information about Terraria.

#### The Guide

When you first enter a new world, you'll see another person walking around the landscape nearby. This NPC is the Guide, who can provide useful information for new players, as well as lists of items that can be crafted from materials you have. You can talk to him by right-clicking him while you are standing close to him.

#### The Wiki

Once you're a bit more experienced with the game and have progressed some, the advice given by the Guide will start to be less useful, and eventually he will stop providing new information at all. By this point, you should probably be familiarizing yourself with [The Official Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terraria_Wiki), where you can find lots of helpful information about every item, enemy, NPC, and event in the game. Do be wary of looking around too much, as much of the fun of a sandbox game like Terraria is in discovering new things on your own, but how much you follow that advice is up to you.

As mentioned by Mani5556, the Wiki also has a [Getting Started guide](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Getting_started), which should be helpful to a new player.

### But the Console and Mobile versions do

According to Joishi Bodio and CodeMoose, the console and mobile versions of Terraria do have a tutorial world, apparently consisting of a small, predetermined world on a floating island. The player is given various instructions on the controls and how to perform basic tasks such as mining and constructing a house for NPCs, before being recommended to create a normal world. More information about the tutorial can be found [on the Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tutorial), though it doesn't include the actual information from the tutorial, only a summary.

Comment: There's also [a wiki hosted on Wikia](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Terraria_Wiki); I don't remember it being as good, and only had to refer to it a very few times, the official one being almost exhaustive.

Comment: Note that it might not take long to get to the wanting-to-refer-to-the-wiki stage. For instance, not only is house-building good for keeping you alive at night--a problem you quickly run into--but if you build (or repair) a few houses, you get more NPCs. While the GUI will give you some hints about how to do this (via the [?] button, say), flipping to the wiki will give you quick, concrete info about the requirements for a valid house.

Comment: I would like to point out that the console version of Terraria DOES have a tutorial.  The PC version does not.  (I own both)  I am unsure of the mobile version.

Comment: Also, as a side note, terraria pocket edition has a tutorial. I know it's irrelevant but I just want to clarify, as a lot of people are saying that there is no tutorial at all.

Comment: There is the option to start a tutorial world - http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tutorial

Comment: @CodeMoose Thank you for confirming that it's also available in the Mobile version. However, it's not available in the PC version, which the question was originally targeted at.

Answer (score 8):

I have a little addition to Mike Kellogg's answer and since it seems like I can't comment yet, due to lack of reputation, I will put it as a separate answer.

Terraria itself doesn't have a tutorial as Mike's answer said, but what it does have is In-Game-Achievements, which will help you getting started and which will lead you through the progression of the game and the order of the bosses. You can't call it a tutorial, but it's a hint on what to do first and where to go from that.

Comment: thanks! I learned this from the guide he linked me but still thank you for the info